# Error conversion from Boolean to String

Tags: vba, visual-studio

Why do I keep receiving this error:

> Conversion from String type to Boolean is not valid.

When coding:

```
ElseIf Word = ("aardwolf") Or ("aardwola") Then
```

Or is unconvert-able to String?

Comment: Try `ElseIf Word = ("aardwolf") Or Word = ("aardwola") Then`. Problem is that ("aardwola")` after `Or` is a `String` not a `boolean` value as error states

Comment: You should tag your question with the language you are using. `visual-studio` is an IDE, and not a language. It looks like `visual basic`. Secondly, you will find that error messages will mostly shed a lot of light on what you are doing wrong. In this case, the compiler thinks you want to perform a `Boolean` operation on a string, which isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ElseIf Word = ("aardwolf") Or Word = ("aardwola") Then
```